# Ionic 3 Canvas Creation in Provider

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I followed this tutorial to be able to use the canvas API inside of ionic:
http://masteringionic.com/blog/2017-05-02-using-html5-canvas-with-ionic/

The issue is, I now have to have all of the functions regarding the canvas inside the pages class, which is a lot, and it will need to be used by multiple other pages. I tried to put all of my code into a provider but when it gets to the following code it throws errors:

```
this.canvas = this.canvasEl.nativeElement;
```

canvasEl is referenced from:

`@ViewChild('canvas') canvasEl: ElementRef;`

Not sure where to go from here, I believe the issue is that @viewchild isn't able to find anything with the #canvas tag, but I don't know how to add a html page for the provider to look at and find.

Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK I cleaned up my answer and recreated the use case in a simple reference implementation:

1. Created blank Ionic 3 app: ionic start blank
2. Modified home page's home.html to be:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  Below is Home Page's 320px*320px canvas:
  <canvas #homepagecanvas></canvas>
</ion-content>
```

3. Added the following code to the home.ts:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CanvasProviderService } from '../../providers/canvasProvider';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('homepagecanvas') homepagecanvas: ElementRef;

  private homePageCanvasCtx: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private canvasProvider: CanvasProviderService
  ) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.homePageCanvasCtx = this.homepagecanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.homePageCanvasCtx.drawImage(this.canvasProvider.canvasRef, 0, 0)
      console.log("rendered from provider!")
    }, 3000)
  }

}
```

4. Added canvasProvider:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// this image is just for example of what you can render into canvas:

const exampleImage = document.createElement('img');
exampleImage.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png')
exampleImage.setAttribute('width', "120");
exampleImage.setAttribute('height', "120");

@Injectable()
export class CanvasProviderService {

  public canvasRef: any;
  public canvasCtx: any;

  public examplePic: any;

  constructor() {
    this.canvasRef = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.canvasRef.width = 320;
    this.canvasRef.height = 320;
    this.canvasCtx = this.canvasRef.getContext('2d');
    this.examplePic = exampleImage;
    this.canvasCtx.drawImage(exampleImage, 0, 0);
  }

}
```

Don't forget to import and add this provider in your app.module.ts...

Now run this app and you will see that Google logo that is originally rendered in the provider can be "copied" into the canvas of your component (page).

The example image (google logo) is just to prove the concept. You can render whatever you want in this canvas-in-provider and then get it rendered in your canvas-in-page.

Let me know if this is clear and works for you.

PS: I used "const" etc block in the provider mostly cause I was experimenting. You can do the assignments in the constructor or as appropriate according to Angular and it should work np as well.

UPDATE: 
As Tim pointed out in comments - one needs to pay attention to sizing (width/height) of canvases to avoid cut offs

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. I can use the canvas already within the page, the issue is I want to transfer all of the code manipulating it into a provider.

If I create a const htmlCanvasElement inside the page, I still can't use it within the provider, or am  I missing something? I have tried passing the canvas as a parameter to the provide with no luck, I get the: "Cannot resolve all parameter for providername" error. 

The second idea of having it within the menu however will be my last resort, thanks heaps for the help so far.

Comment: That is why my answer is to create the canvas in you provider;) try it and let me know

Comment: Okay that has removed all errors and the page can see the functions and call them (I put logs in to make sure), however it does not draw anything on the page, because I guess it has nowhere to draw them or doesn't know which element it's drawing to. How do I link the const canvas in the provider to a canvas in the html page? Sorry for so many questions, I am a C programmer generally but I have to make an app for uni and I'm new to JS and TS. Thanks again

Comment: I have tried returning the const canvas element in a function inside the provider then using: document.insertBefore(this.provider.thatfunction(), divElement);
But no luck

Comment: Hey Tim, you dont need to link it in any way - it is your canvas. Whatever methods you had that used canvas should use it now. If you struggle share your provider code in the question. I can help clarify the usage

Comment: I will add a screencap of how i use it in my case

Comment: I feel like you are probably trying to use those methods from the article like initializeCanvas correct?

Comment: Please share your full provider code and i will help fix it. Basically all the canvas “api”s (methods) are already available to you through myHtmlCanvas constant, i can help show how you use it

Comment: thats the photos of the provider and page.

Comment: the provider code is huge and has heaps of functions so I didn't show them all, basically I call them, they run but don't draw on the tutorial.html page

Comment: Ok last question

Comment: I see my mistake;) i thought you need to perform certain actions without actually showing things to users. Let me add suggestion in a few mins

Comment: yeah I thought so, it's pretty challenging to work out but I will likely have to make more than four pages with the same functions used so I really don't want to have all of them written for each page.

Comment: Hey Kaiido i will update those into code snippets on monday. Had to be on mobile and cant copy paste:((

Comment: @TimMallett I updated the answer, did you try this route?

Comment: Ok I rereated the case and will update my answer with tested code

Comment: Hi, just saw this, I'll give it a try and let you know, thanks.

Comment: Be aware that the image I used might no longer be valid / exist;) also in your case you will have to write more code to "clear" canvas of any content otherwise it will all "stack".

Comment: That worked!! So basically to summarise it, you have to draw what you want in the providers canvas, and then you create a canvas on the page like I had done originally, and draw the whole canvas that is drawn in the provider. As a side note for anyone else struggling with this, you have to size the canvas on your page, not just the canvas in the provider. If the pages canvas isn't big enough, it will cut off the drawing.